# Clone a <form></form> tag and wrap it around existing content?

Tags: jquery, html, append, clone

So There is an existing form tag as such:

```
<form id="vCSS_mainform" onsubmit="javascript:return QtyEnabledAddToCart_SuppressFormIE();" action="/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=40124" name="MainForm" method="post">Bunch of Content</form>
```

There is a bunch of content inside of this form tag. I need to take just the  element of it, clone it, and wrap it around another TABLE element that I have on the page.

I don't want anything in the form tag to be cloned. Is this possible?

I can't just do $("p").wrapAll(""); because that form action contains dymanic content that changes. So i need to find the form tag on whatever page the user is on and clone that exact one.

Comment: SO you want this part: <form ...>[ignoreThisStuff]</form>?

Comment: Indeed, and I just need to wrap just the <form></form> around my new content

Comment: As a side note, `javascript:` is not required for `onsubmit`, because only Javascript can be run from it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unwrap a form tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174586/unwrap-a-form-tag)

Answer (score 2):

```
var $clone = $('#vCSS_mainform').clone().empty().attr('id', 'newId');
$('#vCSS_mainform').remove(); // only if you don't need it anymore.
$('#yourTable').wrap($clone);
```

note: if you remove the original form, you don't need to set a new id for the clone (no need of `.attr('id', 'newId')`)

Comment: upvoted, great call on the id. the 1 line version of this (without deleting old form) is: `$("yourTable").wrap($("#vCSS_mainform").clone().empty().attr('id', 'newid'));`

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively easy to achieve, really all you have to do, is use `.clone()`, `.append()` and `.empty()`:

```
$('#vCSS_mainform').clone().appendTo($('body')).empty();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MHHeP/).

Bear in mind, of course, that duplicate `id`s are invalid HTML.

---

**Edited** to complete the answer, to wrap the `#accBox` you could use:

```
$('#accBox').wrap($('#vCSS_mainform').clone().appendTo($('body')).empty());
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/MHHeP/1/).

References:

- [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).
- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).
- [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Comment: That gave me this HTML structure in Firebug:

<div id="accBox">

<h4>Accessories</h4>

<td class="accBoxTD" width="15%" valign="top">

<form id="vCSS_mainform" onsubmit="javascript:return QtyEnabledAddToCart_SuppressFormIE();" action="/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=40124" name="MainForm" method="post"></form>


The <form> tag needs to wrap around the <div id="accBox">

Comment: Note: you can just do `.appendTo('body')`.

Comment: `.appendTo()` isn't needed as `.wrap()` will add the empty cloned element onto the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#accBox").wrap($('#vCSS_mainform').clone().empty());
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HhBQd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try someting like this.

```
function strip(htmlfullstring)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("formid");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return <form> + tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText+</form>;
}
```

if i understood your requirement.