# Unwrap a form tag

Tags: jquery, html, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Clone a <form></form> tag and wrap it around existing content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8174058/clone-a-form-form-tag-and-wrap-it-around-existing-content)

This is the main HTML structure from Firebug. I didn't include any inside content or anything because there is to much. I asked a previous question similar but it didn't work. I am hoping I can get the following to work. I need to "unwrap" the FORM tag that you see but keep whatever content is inside it where it is. Then I need to take that same FORM tag and make it wrap around the table right underneath the < DIV ID="TOP_NAV">.

```
<div id="content">
<div id="top_nav">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="nav_menu" class="bgcolor2 colors_background2 colors_background2_text" valign="top">
<td id="main_content" valign="top">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div id="content_area">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="/a/j/product_details.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/a/j/product_details.js" type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<form id="vCSS_mainform" onsubmit="javascript:return QtyEnabledAddToCart_SuppressFormIE();" action="/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=40124" name="MainForm" method="post">
<span class="PageText_L493n"></span>
<br>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry im lost .... unwrap a form tag !??!?!?!

Comment: There is a <form>LOTS OF CONTENT</form> tag. I need to take JUST the <form> tag and move it somewhere else..

Comment: A `<form>` tag doesnt display on the screen - its affectively a wrapper that contains form elements (such as `input`, `textarea` etc) - can you drap a picture or explain how you want the page laid out ? the form tag can be anywhere on the page

Answer (score 0):

I guess this code will do the work for you. It may be optimized, I just implemented the solution and I'll leave the optimization to you.

```
    // create a clone of the form element
    var cloneForm = $("#vCSS_mainform").clone();

    // move the contents of the form to the outside div
    $("#content_area").html(cloneForm.html());

    // replace the contents of the form with the contents of top_nav div
    cloneForm.hide().html($("#top_nav").html());

    // set the top_nav div to contain the form and form's contents
    $("#top_nav").html(cloneForm);

    // show the form
    cloneForm.show();
```